# Magento - Rewriting Templates: Alternative Approach?

Tags: magento, php

After searching for articles regarding template rewrites, I've done a successful one written on the article [here](http://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento/).


However, as stated in the article, one would have to copy the contents from the original .phtml file to your custom .phtml file. This is where the problem lies -- since we're a team handling different modules at a time, it may come to a point where they would need to overwrite the .phtml file I've written and do the same process -- copying the contents from the original (Which in this case, should be my custom .phtml) to their custom .phtml, which isn't upgrade safe at all because any future changes that I make on my module will not reflect on the template as my colleague has already rewritten it.


Would there be another approach for this? Or would the only way around this is to merge our code into a single custom .phtml file?

Comment: Every one working on the same template file itself ?

Comment: Did you tried using SVN ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy We are actually using SVN.Let's say I've already finished creating my module -- let's name it MyModule. I've used this module to rewrite a specific template file and it's working fine. And then my teammate works on another module -- Let's name it HisModule. So what he did was he rewrote the custom template I built to add another functionality to it. But because the article I mentioned just copied my code to his .phtml file, the future changes in mine (MyModule) will not reflect as his .phtml file is being called. (HisModule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to modify HTML via Magneto event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`.

So that multiple modules can add modifications upgrade safe.

Downside is using regular expressions or xml changes in the code, not in the templates.

Comment: What could you suggest that can be done? Would it actually be possible for modules to be linked to a single template file that will overwrite the intended template file? It is the only possible solution I can think of at the moment, since I'm all out of ideas.